# Rails 3 remote resubmit form with dynamic fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a form which has `remote => true`. When i submit it the first time everything works well.

If there are any errors i want to add new fields to this form. I did this with `update.js.erb`.

The problem is that when i resubmit this form, the result js file is rendered as html (ie i see the js file text on the screen). This is the same `update.js.erb` file that was rendered as js the first time...

Any idea what i'm missing?

UPDATE:
On the first try, format is:

```
format
=> #<ActionController::MimeResponds::Collector:0xc61711c
 @order=[text/javascript],
 @responses={text/javascript=>nil}>
```

On the second submit it's:

```
format
=> #<ActionController::MimeResponds::Collector:0xceaadec 
@order=[], 
@responses={}>
```

my update.js is just basically

```
$("#checkout_modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'plan_pay_modal')%>");
```

and plan_pay_modal is the same partial as on the original page (a form which will show new fields if there are errors. I also tried just the fields same problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out the problem was that i was submitting through jquery

```
form$.get(0).submit()
```

does not work in this case... To get working i had to use

```
form$.trigger("submit.rails")
```

[rails 3 how do i submit a remote form with jquery and avoid callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394814/rails-3-how-do-i-submit-a-remote-form-with-jquery-and-avoid-callbacks)

Answer (score 0):

If you see the javascript as content in your web browser, it means that the request sent by your browser was a normal html request instead of a ajax request.  This in turn means that the form for some reason isn't set to :remote => true the second time you submit it.  I suggest you investigate why this is the case or paste some code so that I can help you further.

You can validate that what I'm saying is correct by responding like this in your controller action:

```
respond_to do |format|  
  format.html  { raise "Request is not ajax based!" }
  format.js { render 'update' }
end
```

EDIT:

The second post doesn't look right, so the update.js.erb probably modifies the form in such a way that it can't work correctly anymore.  Why not render the same content that was previously in the modal.  In other words originally on the page you show a partial in the modal, then the update.js.erb just rerenders that partial and replaces the modal content.  You can have if's in the partial that activate the new dynamic fields that is added if there are errors.

Comment: For your edit: that's what is going on. The js just renders the same partial that is used on the original page

Comment: You are correct, the browser does request html instead of ajax on the second request. I checked the html on the page and data-remote is set to true. Seems like this is a binding issue...

Comment: Must be, investigate your html with browser inspect element and compare it to what a normal :remote => true form should be.  But I personally would stick to rerendering the same partial in that modal.

Comment: turns out the javascript code to validate the form is to blame. Without it everything works. I'll keep digging. Thanks