# rails 3 how do i submit a remote form with jquery and avoid callbacks

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a `remote => true` form and would like to submit it AND avoid a submit method.

Usually i would do

```
form$.get(0).submit()

form$.submit(function(){..avoid going here..})
```

but this sends the form as html instead of js. Any way to do this and get js in response?

Thanks!

Comment: what call back you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

man that i was a pain to find.

the answer is replace

```
$(form).get(0).submit()

$(form)[0].submit()
```

by

```
$(form).trigger("submit.rails")
```

this will skip all submit even listeners except the rails one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your controller

```
respond_to do |page|
    page.js {}
end
```

and add a file in your view with controller's function name ending with .js extension.